# In angular, the size of my main.js file is 20mb and vendor.js file is 7mb, what could be the issue and how can I optimize my build?

Tags: angular, optimization, npm-package, ng-build, local-node-modules

Size of main.js = 20mb and size of vendor.js = 7.84mb, what could be the issue and how can I optimize my build?

I tried using ng build --prod which gives error for version 15.2-15.3

Comment: Do you have `"optimization": false` in your `angular.json` file? This could cause large builds. https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

Comment: No, "optimization" is true in my angular.json file.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing it with the [bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)?

Comment: You can probably use `gzip compression` to compress the static or dynamic files